# webpack babel loaders for es6 dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I have some dependencies that use es6, and some that do not. What's the best way to use a babel loader with these dependencies? Right now, I manually specify each es6 dependency in my `webpack-dist.conf.js` file, but this feels hacky and I was hoping there was some automatic way to put `node_modules` declared in `package.json` dependencies through babel if necessary.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Comment: We have babel process all your JavaScript files, no matter whether they use ES6 features or not. No issues so far. Are you facing performance problems with this approach?

Comment: @Timo I guess I could read the package.json and programatically include those directories. It's a bit slower because I'm including angular, but at least that's more sensible.

Comment: Like @Timo said, just "babel" all of them. You could try renaming them to `.es6` then run `babel-loader` for those file types only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your webpack's config:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Then you are telling webpack that babel-loader is used for all `".js"` files